# Stop downloading of audio files but still be able to play it

Tags: ios, afnetworking, download

I am currently working on an App which requires me to download a certain audio file. I am using AFNetworking for downloading and it works very well. What I want to achieve is when I download a file, I can stop it manually but still be able to play the audio file to where I stopped the downloading.

I have tried to work on it but what I always get is that when the downloading of the file is stopped, I can't play the audio. It maybe because the file is incomplete and will be considered as corrupted. The audio formats that I am downloading are m4a and AIFF.

Is this possible? Please help me on achieving it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding manually the signature of the audio file at the start/end.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Is your problem being unable to play the audio after stopping, or is it that it actually keeps playing although you've stopped downloading?